# how to level link against angular's material input?

Tags: angular-material2

how to level link (and any other text) against angular's material (6.3.3) input?

```
<div>
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Input" matInput >
      </mat-form-field>

      <a style="cursor: pointer;text-decoration: underline;">click</a>
</div>
```

instead of this

[image]

should be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both look quite bad IMO. I think your desired result is worse because the text baselines do line line up. Links in Material Design are not styled liked traditional links. They may have a different color, and a hover effect, but underlining is not typically used. If you use a highlight/hover color instead of the underline as well as the cursor (or use a button `<a mat-button>`) it will line up properly and look "material".

Comment: (un)fortunately my task is just to dully implement what is given in the proto.